# Remove & characters with regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm a bit stuck on a issue i'm having with regex

This is my string: `&Biblioteks&klasse &Test something & something`

This is my expected result: `Biblioteksklasse Test something & something`

This is my actual result: `Biblioteksklasse Test something something`

Here is my regrex: `/^&|(?=\D)&/`

Anyone knows how I can get to my actual result?

Comment: Can you show what your code is to get your current result?

Comment: What are the requirements of the match?

Comment: tried breaking the array on the basis of spaces and then deleting the & if it is the first character?

Comment: Use `/&(?=\S)/`

Comment: @Mohammad returns "Biblioteks&klasse &Test something & something"

Comment: `s.replace(/&\b|\b&/g, '')`? See https://regex101.com/r/Jm2y2s/1

Comment: Wiktor, thanks! Works fine!

Comment: @ChristianMoen Please don't create games of "spot the difference", instead *explain* what is the difference between actual & desired output. I had to look 3 times to see it.

Comment: @PeterB I'm sorry. That will be in my thoughts next time I create a question..

Comment: @user202729 [It is posted with more details.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53392968/3832970)

Comment: Should & be removed if they're at the end of a word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want to remove `&` if it is next to a word char.

In this case, use

```
s.replace(/&\b|\b&/g, '')
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Jm2y2s/1/). `&\b` matches `&` that is followed with a word char (letter, digit or `_`) and `\b&`  matches `&` that is preceded with a word char.

If you plan to remove it when it is next to a non-whitespace char, use

```
s.replace(/&(?=\S)|(\S)&/g, '$1')
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Jm2y2s/2/). It matches:

- `&(?=\S)`  - a `&` that is followed with a non-whitespace char
- `|` - or
- `(\S)` - Group 1 (later referred to with `$1` from the replacement pattern): any non-whitespace char
- `&` - a `&` char.

Answer (score 1):

Using a lookbehind you could write:

```
/(&(?=\w)|(?<=\w)&)/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple regex:

```
&(?=\w)
```

It matches an '`&`' and looks ahead to ensure it's followed by a Word character.

Then you `replace` with an `empty string`.

**How to use:**

```
var text = '&Biblioteks&klasse &Test something & something';
var regex = /&(?=\w)/g;
var output = regex.replace(text, '');
```

Comment: The `&(?=\w)` is equal to `&\b`. It is actually part of my answer.